# Error al importar modulo con webpack y laravel mix

Tags: javascript, laravel, npm, webpack

Soy nuevo con todo esto de npm y webpack, siempre habia usado CDN. Estoy implementando la plantilla adminlte3 y ya conseguí importar algunos plugins que ya trae esta plantilla de la siguiente forma.

En bootstrap.js (no es el framework)

```
try {
    window.Popper = require('popper.js').default;
    window.$ = window.jQuery = require('jquery');

    require('bootstrap');
    require('admin-lte');
} catch (e) {}
```

En app.js

```
require('./bootstrap');
import 'admin-lte/plugins/datatables/jquery.dataTables.min.js';
import 'admin-lte/plugins/datatables-bs4/js/dataTables.bootstrap4.min.js';
import 'admin-lte/plugins/datatables-responsive/js/dataTables.responsive.min.js';
import 'admin-lte/plugins/datatables-responsive/js/responsive.bootstrap4.min.js';

import toastr from 'admin-lte/plugins/toastr/toastr.min.js';
window.toastr = toastr;

import swal from 'admin-lte/plugins/sweetalert2/sweetalert2.min.js';
window.Swal = swal;

import 'admin-lte/plugins/select2/js/select2.min.js';
```

Todo me funciona perfectamente solo que al agregar Summernote me lanza un error

```
import 'admin-lte/plugins/summernote/summernote.min.js'
```

y el error es este

Warning: jQuery, There are multiple modules with names that only differ in casing. This can lead to unexpected behavior

Ya revisé y la ruta a ese archivo es correcta.

Comment: probá esto https://github.com/summernote/summernote/issues/4200

Comment: Gracias, con eso resolví el problema.

Answer (score 1):

al parecer existe un conflicto por la mayúscula de jQuery y jquery, entonces lo único que tenemos que hacer es ir al archivo webpack.mix.js y agregar lo siguiente

```
mix.webpackConfig({
    resolve: {
        alias: {
            jQuery: 'jquery',
        },
    }
});
```